# C# generics and special case for void

Tags: c#, generics, async-await

I wrote a function that will, using the relatively new async/await pattern run any function on a thread and notify the caller later via an optional callback method. The function is super simple and looks like this:

```
private async void DoOperationAsync<T>(Func<T> operation, Action<T> resultAction = null)
{
    if (operation == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("operation");

    var result = await Task<T>.Factory.StartNew(operation);

    // Notify someone that this finished
    if (resultAction != null)
        resultAction(result);
}
```

This works very well for functions that return a value. It doesn't work for is functions that return void (Or maybe I'm not smart enough to make it work). I could write a special case of this method that doesn't assume a return type. However, I wonder if some C# generics gurus could point out a way to handle void in this case. Is there are way for that to work that doesn't involve a special case for void functions?

Comment: How does your method differ from the `ContinueWith` method that is already implemented on `Task`?

Comment: In general you should expect that `void`, unfortunately, needs to be handled specially. Generic types do not handle `void` gracefully.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I was thinking I would have to handle void as a special case and you confirmed it. There isn't much difference with ContinueWith except the continuation method doesn't need to be wrapped in a Task.

Comment: The whole point of using tasks is so that you don't *have* to be passing in callback methods; you just pass around tasks and people use `ContinueWith` themselves.  A method like this is generally contrary to the design of the TPL.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What thread will the ContinueWith task execute on? I do want that method to run on the calling thread (in my case, it will be the main UI thread of my application in general).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that you may find helpful.

> I wrote a function that will, using the relatively new async/await pattern run any function on a thread and notify the caller later via an optional callback method.

That's what `Task.Run` is for.

> I do want that method to run on the calling thread (in my case, it will be the main UI thread of my application in general).

And `await` already does that.

So, instead of writing code like this:

```
DoOperationAsync(() =>
{
  // Code that runs on threadpool thread.
  return 13;
},
result =>
{
  // Code that runs on UI thread.
  MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
});
```

Just do this:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() =>
{
  // Code that runs on threadpool thread.
  return 13;
});
// Code that runs on UI thread.
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

P.S. `Task.Run` already has all the necessary overloads for handling delegates with and without return values.

Answer (score 1):

For `async` methods that are void use the type of `Task`

Answer (score 0):

Try having a non generic version of the method which awaits a non generic task before executing the callback

```
private async void DoOperationAsync(Func operation, Action resultAction = null)
{
    if (operation == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("operation");

    await Task.Factory.StartNew(operation);

    // Notify someone that this finished
    if (resultAction != null)
        resultAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid wrapping `Task<T>.Factory.StartNew`. Use it directly instead, and favour `Task.Run` over it where possible, as [@StephenCleary advises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21268521/2674222) in his answer.

Nevertheless, I think your question still makes sense for some other patterns. If you do not want to implement generic and non-generic versions of the method, you can use fake `Empty` struct as generic parameter. For example, there is `TaskCompletionSource<T>` class and `Task.FromResult<T>` method type in TPL, they do not have non-generic versions. If you do not want to leak the information, the code may look similar to this:

```
public struct Empty {
    public static Empty Value {
        get { return default(Empty); }
}

static Task GetCompletedTask() { 
    return Task.FromResult(Empty.Value); }
```

You can turn any `void` method into `Empty` func:

```
static Func<Empty> Func(Action action) {
    return () => { action(); return Empty.Value; };
}

DoOperationAsync(Func(() =>
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!")));
```

This can make it work with your existing generic method, without leaking any result to the caller.